# How do I set up HAProxy Behind Cloudfront for Jenkins

Tags: reverse-proxy, http, haproxy, jenkins, amazon-cloudfront

Ok the network so far is

```
end user (https)-> cloudfront (http)-> haproxy (http)-> jenkins
```

My jenkins install mostly works but I see the error about proxy not being set up correctly, and I experience https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14313

I've read the following, but encountered some confusing issues.

1. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+HAProxy
2. https://gist.github.com/xelwarto/ac4f8b43e4194355082c

This is what I've come up with so far

```
defaults
    mode http
    retries 3
    timeout connect 120s
    timeout client 60s
    timeout server 60s
resolvers docker
    nameserver dns "127.0.0.11:53"
frontend web
    bind *:8080
    default_backend jenkins
backend jenkins
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server jenkins jenkins:8080 check cookie s1 resolvers docker resolve-prefer ipv4
    acl h_cfp_exists req.hdr(CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto) -m found
    acl response-is-redirect res.hdr(Location) -m found
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if h_cfp_exists
```

Here's the headers(headers have had their domain and secure strings mangled, slashes and names preserved) received by jenkins

```
    POST /j_acegi_security_check HTTP/1.1
    Host: jenkins.default.mydomain.tld
    X-Amz-Cf-Id: _UoBjzMmiJvkMZOnRbt6Ai2rBZ4hm1jAz_5IGAi3OwI9TxQ5tCW5Bg==
    Content-Length: 339
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36 OPR/49.0.2725.64
    Via: 2.0 9a063989aee4dbd9381a2cf612c17c08.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
    Cookie: JSESSIONID.0262fa7d=node01f8yc6mw0a5p6gv09wvy275j610.node0; JSESSIONID.9f7e10bd=node01i3tan71bopiv2ufhmos5dccq83.node0; JSESSIONID.d3f1b83b=node0nqkbin0vx70f12cdr9kmgatyk6.node0
    X-Forwarded-For: 2605:6000:1025:bd:31c7:df4d:6bd6:8b9c
    CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer: false
    CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer: false
    CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer: false
    CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer: true
    CloudFront-Viewer-Country: US
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    Referer: https://jenkins.default.mydomain.tld/
    CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto: https
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    cache-control: max-age=0
    origin: https://jenkins.default.mydomain.tld
    upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
    content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
```

and the response as received by the browser

```
content-length:0
date:Wed, 10 Jan 2018 15:45:21 GMT
expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
location:https://jenkins.default.mydomain.tld/
server:Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)
set-cookie:JSESSIONID.d3f1b83b=node01o.node0;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
set-cookie:ACEGI_SECURITY_HASHED_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=Y2N1c2hpbmc6MTUxNjgwODcyMTQ5OTpmMmIzNDVkYjE2ODdhRlMGJmNWYz;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 24-Jan-2018 15:45:21 GMT;Max-Age=1209600;Secure;HttpOnly
status:302
via:1.1 6d16d2818.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id:WZMDdUGVK4fRg6E04gN2sr9RIgKDqeK0-kAANBbeu7eB3uFv9cAkQw==
x-cache:Miss from cloudfront
x-content-type-options:nosniff
```

I then see a subsequent `GET /login HTTP/1.1` but I don't understand why it'd be doing that. Also possibly of interest, there is no default view set in configure globals, in fact the configuration for that seems to be absent. *accessed over http, via haproxy everything is fine* well the warning still shows, seems I can fix that by setting the jenkins uri to use http://IP:port.

how do I fix my haproxy setup such that jenkins login will not show the login form where the dashboard should be? can anyone explain the transformations that need to be done in a proxy technology agnostic way and why (.e.g. examples seem to show 127.0.0.1:8080, but htat's obviously not going to work for me, however since Location is returning https, I'm not sure why I'd need to do anything like that)?

Comment: I don't see any ssl section in your haproxy setup. Also you should pass Host http header

Comment: @ALex_hha cloudfront is doing the tls termination, and it adds host which appears to be passed fine.

Comment: @ALex_hha added headers for the login request

Comment: Just for reference - what's the point of using Jenkins behind Cloudfront?

Comment: @ALex_hha consistent setup with other services, auto cert renewal from amazon. I honestly wouldn't be using haproxy at all if cloudfront was able to add the appropriate `X-Forwarded-Proto`. Well, I say that, but now I think this all a nasty jenkins bug. Jenkins simply isn't doing the right thing in all cases when that is set. However, my next attempt will prove or disprove that.

Comment: also, at this point cloudfront is my tls termination, and not having that at all is not a good idea.